# Suggesting future work in technical report

Tags: publications, thesis

I’m writing a report for my bachelor’s degree and have come to the last section where I am supposed to suggest future work. As I have learned, while writing the conclusion-section just before the future work section, I am not supposed to present new details. All conclusions must be supported by previous parts of the report.

My question is if this normally also applies to the future work section? I have a few ideas of my own of what can be done to broaden the research question that I cannot support by, for example, something I have written about in the background section (where I describe theory), related work section (where I investigate state-of-the-art), etc.

So basically, is it bad to all of a sudden include information based on my own experience, or kind of my intuition, in the very final part of the report? To be a bit more concrete, if I have a theory that I did not investigate as it did not really help me answering the research question, hence not supported by any reference, would it be possible to express it as something that is based on my own experience and impression of the field, and suggest that it should be investigated?

Comment: In general I would say yes, write it. However, there might be rules concerning such questions at your institute, so I suggest to ask the advisor about it. He/she might also be able to tell you if the questions and open problems you found are interesting, have already been solved somewhere, etc.